# Not able get data for today

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have below procedure MY_PROC.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROC(
    IN_VAR_FROM_DATE IN VARCHAR2,
    OUT_DATA OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
  TEMP_DATE DATE;
BEGIN
  TEMP_DATE :        = NVL(TO_DATE(IN_VAR_FROM_DATE,'DD-MON-RRRR'),SYSDATE);
  IF(IN_VAR_FROM_DATE='CM') THEN
    TEMP_DATE       := SYSDATE;
  END IF;
  OPEN OUT_DATA FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATE_COLUMN>=TRUNC(TEMP_DATE );
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  NULL;
END MY_PROC;
```

Now in above proc, When i am passing null as input param, i am getting values for sysdate. i want same when i will pass "CM" as input param but instead i am getting no data.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What actually happens when you run a to_date function on 'CM'?

Comment: Remove the WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL. This may hide the actual problem.

Comment: First of all - remove that OTHERS exception and everything will be clear. Then think about what you are passing in parameter IN_VAR_FROM_DATA. If it is date formatted as string - why not passing regular date type? If it can be various data (string, date, etc) I think you should redesign that procedure, but at least you should check input string for validity, instead of using OTHERS exception which in this case just masks the error.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm. . . I think this is the logic you want:

```
OPEN OUT_DATA FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE DATE_COLUMN >= (CASE WHEN IN_VAR_FROM_DATE IS NULL OR IN_VAR_FROM_DATE  = 'CM'
                               THEN TRUNC(sysdate)
                               ELSE TO_DATE(IN_VAR_FROM_DATE, 'DD-MON-RRRR')
                          END);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to when you are passing 'CM' as input parameter your procedure tries to convert the CM in to date and you are getting exception in this case.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROC(
    IN_VAR_FROM_DATE IN VARCHAR2,
    OUT_DATA OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
  TEMP_DATE DATE;
BEGIN


  IF(IN_VAR_FROM_DATE='CM') THEN
    TEMP_DATE       := SYSDATE;
  ELSE
    TEMP_DATE :        = NVL(TO_DATE(IN_VAR_FROM_DATE,'DD-MON-RRRR'),SYSDATE);
  END IF;
  OPEN OUT_DATA FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATE_COLUMN>=TRUNC(TEMP_DATE );
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  NULL;
END MY_PROC;
```